# Login functionality in laravel 4.2 based on database records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am fairly new to laravel and I am trying to create a login functionality in laravel 4.2 where the username and password is fetched from the database. I am planning to use this code in the controller but i don't know how to tweak it in such a way that the username and password should be based from a database record

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $credentials = [
        'username'=>Input::get('username'),
        'password'=>Input::get('password')
    ];
    $rules = [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password'=>'required'
    ];

    //validating the credentials.
    $validator = Validator::make($credentials,$rules);

    //in case the credentials are valid. Try to login the user.
    if($validator->passes())
    {
        if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
        {
            //if successfull redirect the user 
            return Redirect::to('user/home');
        }
        //else send back the login failure message.
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('failure','username or password is invalid!');
    }
        //send back the validation errors.
    return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}


public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('/');
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to tweak that code. Default behavior of `Auth` is to use the `eloquent` driver which uses the database you configured with your app.

So `Auth::attempt($credentials)` will use the database table associated (default `users` table) to authenticate the user with the provided credentials.

You can change the model or table name like opitons in `Auth.php` file in `config` directory.

**Edit**

To validate and login a user manually use the following.

```
public function postLogin()
{
    $credentials = Input::only('username', 'password');

    $validator = Validator::make($credentials, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password'=>'required'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }

    $user = User::where('SystemUserName', $credentials['username'])->first();

    if (! $user || ! Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->SystemUserPassword)) {
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('failure','username or password is invalid!');
    }

    Auth::login($user);
    return Redirect::to('user/home');
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the info. i tried to use it then i got the error `Undefined index: password`

Comment: Which line throws the error. Do you use `$_GET['password']` or `$_GET['password']` anywhere in your code. If so use `Input::get('password')`

Comment: the password in my database in encrypted so i still need to encrypt the value i get from `Input::get('password')` im doing it like this  `$sptkey  = md5('3982f3a0c86f272633fc7105040a83c8');
     $unenc   = Input::get('pword');
     $enPass  = rtrim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $sptkey, $unenc , MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));`

Comment: You need to make sure that the array you pass to `Auth::attempt()` has an index named `password` which contains the plain password. Laravel will compare the plain password to the hashed password behind the scene unless you are using a custom hash for the passwords.

Comment: You can use the laravel built-in hash method using `Hash::make($plainText')`

Comment: what if the username and passwords in my table is name `SystemUserName` `SystemUserPassword`?

Comment: AFAIK you can pass any named field for `Auth::attempt` except for the `password` field as it is hardcoded in the `Eloquent` provider.

Comment: thank you so much i think i need to ask a new question for that :) thanks again!

Comment: I'll update the answer with how to manually validate and login a user. Give me a minute.